# webViewLink now returning "404 Not Found"

Tags: google-apps, google-drive-api

URIs to public folders that were viewable last week via webViewLink now return HTTP 404 - Not Found errors.

The folders are still public, contain index.html and are listed in this test script:

https://googledrive.com/host/0B0YvUuHHn3Mna3Rzb19tLTYyOXc/

Nothing has changed in either the web folders or the webViewLink. Has something changed on the server?

Comment: Enterprise Support have been unable to help with this issue, but I did find a workaround: change permission from "Anyone with the link" to "Public on the web".  I too would like to know if this was a deliberate change.

Comment: This workaround fixes the problem. thank you crb.

If it is an access problem, Google should return "Error 403 Access Denied/Forbidden" not "404 - Not found"

Comment: My Google partner team are escalating it internally, in case this ticket doesn't get an answer first!

Answer (score 2):

This is an intentional change. As mentioned in the comments, "Anyone with the link" will not work, and should be "Public on the web". Google will update the documentation.

This was unfortunately changed without warning to the community, and this is inexcusable. Really sorry if you were bitten by this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got it.
So if you still will not be able to see your html public, **open the index file** and
*File -> Allow viewers to download.*
Yes, and do make the folder and the files shared as "Public on the web".